# SelectboxMixin.selectbox() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hover_data'

Tags: python, web-applications, hover, data-science, streamlit

I was developing the webapp for data science and stuck on the selectbox hover_data feature , it seems its no loger supports the hover_data.

While implementing the selectbox in streamlit webapp it gives following error.
this is the code implemented:

```
select = st.selectbox('Affected type of people', hover_data=['minute','crashes'],height=400)

if select=='Pedestrians':
    st.write(original_data.query("injured_pedestrains>=1")[["on_street_name","injured_pedestrains"]].sort_values(by=['injured_pedestrains'],ascending=False).dropna(how='any')[:5])
```

error:

```
**TypeError: SelectboxMixin.selectbox() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hover_data'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Sandesh Ghimire\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\data-science-webapp\app.py", line 74, in <module>
    select = st.selectbox('Affected type of people', hover_data=['minute','crashes'],height=400)
File "C:\Users\Sandesh Ghimire\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\metrics_util.py", line 356, in wrapped_func
    result = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)**
```

I am unable to find the exact alternative of hover_data so how to implement this?

[Screenshot of error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmnjx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using st_btn_select

```
from st_btn_select import st_btn_select
select= st_btn_select(('Pedestrians','Cyclists','Motorists'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).